# Rudin: $(a,b)$ as subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In his Principles of Mathematical Analysis, example 2.21, Rudin refers to $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$, or to $\mathbb{Z}$ (integers) as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this a common convention?

According to my intuition :), $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not really... comparable. Or is there a convention whereby we say that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as $(x,c)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ (where $c$ is a constant)?

Comment: When it is convenient, one views $\mathbb{R}^n$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ per $(x_1,\dotsc, x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dotsc, x_n,0,\dotsc,0)$.

Comment: It’s sloppy but common.